# Computing $\int_0^{1}\int_{x^2}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \; \;dy\;dx$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I'm trying to solve what seems to be a straightforward double integral but I guess my rewritten integral is wrong. Can this be solved without using a sectant?

My problem:
$$
\int_0^{1}\int_{x^2}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \; \;dy\;dx
$$

Gives:

$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{r}\cdot r\; \;dr\;d\theta
$$

Right? Or did I overlook something?

When I solve that I get $\frac{\pi}{4}$, which is not the correct answer since it should be $\sqrt{2}-1$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried plotting the two versions of your domain? They don't look similar at all

Answer (score 2):

This is just an addition to my comment. The required integration domain is the blue region, you calculated the integral on the orange domain (it continues under the blue domain until the $y=x$ curve).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can see that my area is not correct but I can't figure out how to write it properly.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out, your domain of integration is incorrect. To solve for the correct one, we have that

$$y = x^2 \implies r\sin\theta = r^2\cos^2\theta$$

which gives the integral

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\tan\theta\sec\theta}1\:dr\:d\theta = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan\theta\sec\theta\:d\theta = \sec\theta\Bigr|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \sqrt{2}-1$$

as expected.